What is less coordinating to metals? Triflates or hexafluorophosphates, and why?
I saw a reaction where $\ce{AgOTf}$ and $\ce{AgPF6}$ were used, but I am trying to discern the reactivity between the two silver salts. I read that triflates and hexafluorophosphates are both non-coordinating, but which one coordinates less to metals (which is more non-coordinating)?
When I ventured into the question, I read that $\ce{-OTf}$ has a "higher ionic conductivity" than $\ce{[PF6]-}$, so I assumed that meant that the resonance structures available for triflates means that it coordinates less to metals and behaves more as a free anion than an ionic pair in solution.
Please help and please correct me if my thought process is wrong. I am very much trying to learn more.
Source:
Liew, C.-W.; Ramesh, S. Comparing Triflate and Hexafluorophosphate Anions of Ionic Liquids in Polymer Electrolytes for Supercapacitor Applications. Materials 2014, 7, 4019-4033, DOI: 10.3390/ma7054019

That's not the way to compare them. You need a reaction in which one of them reacts. Both aren't all that great.

Your statement, "I read that triflates and hexafluorophosphates are both non-coordinating," may not exactly correct. Actually, the triflate $(\ce{CF3SO3-})$ is weakly coordinating (Ref.1) while the hexafluorophosphate $(\ce{PF6-})$ (Ref.2) is noncoordinating (Ref.2). The abstract of Ref.3 clearly states this fact:

We show that much like hydrogen bonding, $\ce{Ag−N}$ coordination bonds can be reliably used for the construction of supramolecular networks. From a solid-state structural study of silver(I) complexes of multitopic ligands, we describe coordination networks formed in the presence of the weakly coordinating triflate $(\ce{CF3SO3-})$ counterion and the noncoordinating hexafluorophosphate $(\ce{PF6-})$ species. For complexes prepared with silver(I) triflate, counterion coordination is characteristic. Also, for the triflate complexes presented, ditopic ligands form one-dimensional, chainlike structures and tritopic ligands form 3-connected nets. A tetratopic ligand also forms a 3-connected net due to the triflate-capped silver(I) coordination. In contrast, more varied network topology is seen in complexes of ditopic ligands prepared with silver(I) hexafluorophosphate.

The discussion in Ref.3 clearly indicates Triflate ion shows better coordination with silver metal than that of hexafluorophosphate ion. For example, the reaction of $\ce{AgSO3CF3}$ with 1,4-pyrazine gives a coordinated compound identified as $\ce{[Ag(1,4-pyrazine)_{1.5}CF3SO3]}$ $(\bf{1})$ by x-ray crystallography:

The structure consists of infinite chains of alternating 1,4-pyrazine molecules and silver(I) ions with each chain linked to another by 1,4-pyrazine bridges that form the rungs of a double-stranded “ladder-type” structure (Ref.3). The $\ce{Ag(1)−O}$ bond distance is listed as $\pu{2.590 \mathring{A}}$, compared to the $\ce{Ag(1)−N}$ bond distances, which are listed in the range of $2.246$-$\pu{2.460 \mathring{A}}$.
On the other hand, the reaction of $\ce{AgPF6}$ with 1,4-pyrazine under similar condition also gives a coordinated compound identified as $\ce{[Ag(1,4-pyrazine)](PF6]_{0.5}(OH)_{0.5}}$ $(\bf{2})$ by x-ray crystallography, in which $\ce{Ag(I)}$ is not coordinated with $\ce{PF6}$. $\ce{PF6}$ is just acting as counterion to complex silver ion:

Thus, it is safe to say that the triflate $(\ce{CF3SO3-})$ is at lest coordinating (although comparatively weakly to other ions) while the hexafluorophosphate $(\ce{PF6-})$ is noncoordinating compared to that of triflate ion. This statement is further supported by the preparation of novel iron-triflate complex, $\ce{[Cp^{*}(dppe)FeOSO2CF3]}$ (Ref.4). In the solid state, the triflate is coordinated at the iron center as shown by XRD of $\ce{[Cp^{*}(dppe)FeOSO2CF3]}$ which has shown coordinating bond distance, $d_\ce{Fe-O} = \pu{2.118 \mathring{A}}$. When $(\ce{PF6-})$ is introduced to the system it just acts as a anionic counter ion to positive $\ce{Fe}$-complex center (Ref.4).

References:

Geoffrey A. Lawrance, "Coordinated trifluoromethanesulfonate and fluorosulfate," Chem. Rev. 1986, 86(1), 17–33 (https://doi.org/10.1021/cr00071a002).
Wolfgang Beck and Karlheinz Süenkel, "Metal complexes of weakly coordinating anions. Precursors of strong cationic organometallic Lewis acids," Chem. Rev. 1988, 88(7), 1405–1421 (https://doi.org/10.1021/cr00089a017).
D. Venkataraman, Stephen Lee, Jeffrey S. Moore, Peng Zhang, Keith A. Hirsch, Geoffrey B. Gardner, Aaron C. Covey, and Christine L. Prentice, "Coordination Networks Based on Multitopic Ligands and Silver(I) Salts:  A Study of Network Connectivity and Topology as a Function of Counterion," Chem. Mater. 1996, 8(8), 2030–2040 (https://doi.org/10.1021/cm950594i).
Paul Hamon, Loic Toupet, Thierry Roisnel, Jean-René Hamon, and Claude Lapinte, "Preparation and Characterization of the Triflate Complex $\ce{[Cp^{*}(dppe)FeOSO2CF3]}$: A Convenient Access to Labile Five- and Six-Coordinate Iron(I) and Iron(II) Complexes," European Journal of Inorganic Chemistry 2020, (1), 84-93 (https://doi.org/10.1002/ejic.201901086).


"Noncoordinating" ligands can sure coordinate, at least sometimes. That's why better counterions than hexafluorophosphate were invented.

@Mithoron: I have changed my final conclusive statement according to your point (which is more suitable answer now to OP's question). I appreciate your careful reading.
